# Dependent drop down html that allow distinct values on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am stuck on my website. I have 3 drop down lists on my HTML webpage populated from mysql. For example, in my table I have 5 fields in a column (`option 1`, `option 2`, `option 3`, `option 4`, `option 5`). In my drop down lists, I want to be able to select `option 1` from drop down `list A`, and then not have `option 1` available in drop down list B and C; if I change this to `option 2`, then `option 1` should become available in drop down list B and C - and so forth and so forth.

Is there anyway in doing this? I have been experimenting with php and javascript but have not have any luck.

Below is the code I already have - still fail new to this

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".Qual1").change(function()
            {
                var id=$(this).val();
                var Userid= 
                        <?php
                            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
                            mysql_select_db("mytestdb", $connection) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                            $log_user = $_SESSION['login_user'];
                            $sqlquery = mysql_query("select fnGetUserID('$log_user') as UserID", $connection);
                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery);

                            echo $row['UserID'];
                        ?>;
                var Circuitid = 
                        <?php
                            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
                            mysql_select_db("mytestdb", $connection) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());

                            $race_name = $_SESSION['Race'];
                            $sqlquery = mysql_query("select fnGetCircuitID('$race_name') as RaceID", $connection);
                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery);

                            echo $row['RaceID'];
                        ?>;

                    <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['Race']); ?>;
                var dataString = 'id='+id+'&Userid='+Userid+'&Circuitid='+Circuitid;

                //alert(dataString);

               $.ajax
                ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxDrivers.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                $(".Qual2").html(html);
                } 
                });

            });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Your Home Page</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="profile">
            <b id="Go Back"><a href="profile.php">Go Back</a></b>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b id="welcome">Making Picks for : <i><?php echo  $_SESSION['Race']  ?></i></b>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>

        <form action="">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>Prediction Form</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Qualifying 1:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Qual1" name="Qual1" class="Qual1">

                        <?php

                            $log_user = $_SESSION['login_user'];

                            $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
                            mysql_select_db("mytestdb", $connection) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());            

                            // Get the UserID
                            $sqlquery = mysql_query("select fnGetUserID('$log_user') as UserID", $connection);
                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery);
                            $_SESSION['intUserID'] =$row['UserID'];

                            // Unset Variable to be ised again
                            unset($sqlquery);
                            unset($row);        

                            $race_name = $_SESSION['Race'];

                            // Get the UserID
                            $sqlquery = mysql_query("select fnGetCircuitID('$race_name') as RaceID", $connection);
                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery);
                            $_SESSION['intRaceID'] =$row['RaceID'];

                            $race_id = $_SESSION['intRaceID'];
                            $user_id = $_SESSION['intUserID'];

                            $qual1 = mysql_query("CALL spGetDrivers($user_id,$race_id)");
                            //$rows = mysql_query($qual1) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
                            while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($qual1)){
                                  echo '<option value="'.$rs['pkDriverID'].'">'.$rs["strDriverName"].'</option>';
                              }

                        ?>

                    </select>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Qualifying 2:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Qual2" name="Qual2" class="Qual2">

                        <option selected="selected">--Select Driver--</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15');
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mytestdb", $connection) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());  
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $userID=$_POST['Userid'];
    $CircuitID=$_POST['Circuitid'];

    $rs=mysql_query("CALL spInTempDriver($userID,$CircuitID,$id)");

    //echo '<option value="'.$CircuitID.'">'.$CircuitID.'</option>';

    $sql=mysql_query("CALL spGetDrivers($user_id,$CircuitID)");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $id=$row['pkDriverID'];
        $data=$row['strDriverName'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Give us the code that you have, and then we can help. No one is going to write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yudkczk2/6/) which uses jQuery to disable `option`s if they are already selected in another `select` element.

JS:

```
$(function() {

  $("select").on("change", function() { // select on change event

    var selectedValues = []; // array of all the values selected by any select element
    $("select > option:selected").each(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val != "") { // exlude the value if it is ""
        selectedValues.push(val);
      }
    });

    $("select").not($(this)).each(function() { // for each other select element
      var selectedValue = $(this).val(); // value of the currently selected option for this select element
      $(this).find("option").each(function() { // for each option
        if ($(this).val() != selectedValue && selectedValues.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) { // disable only if not the currently selected option and if it is selected by a select element
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          $(this).show(); // else show the option if it is hidden
        }

      });
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: That works, is there a way to completely remove the option from the drop down list instead of just disable it?

Comment: @Nirmie I've changed it to hide/show the options instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to code event handlers for the changed event of the lists and in that handler, you'll need to evaluate the selected item's value. Once you know that, you can rebuild the other lists.